# Aplicacion Win Forms se cierra Error Exceptio code E0434352

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-forms, .net

Tengo un error en mi aplicacion de escritorio. Se cierra de repente mandando un exception code E0434352

¿Alguno ha tenido este mismo problema? 
La aplicacion esta en RDS osea en servidores todos los usuarios acceden a ella, tipo un escritorio remoto.

Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: Ya lo quite gracias leere las normas.

Comment: Pero necesitamos el error completo, y tambien el codigo que genera el error. Si no, es solo buscar en google ese codigo de error...

Comment: Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name: SICTPL.exe
Application Version: 1.2019.416.0
Application Timestamp: 5cc328f9
Fault Module Name: KERNELBASE.dll
Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.19269
Exception Code. e0434352

Comment: a vos no te esta dando un error el fuente? deberiamos ver el fuente, y probar el fuente a ver que error da. Eso parece mas un error del sistema que de un fuente. googleaste ese error?

Comment: Asi es lo googlee pero como tal no hay una respuesta definitiva al error. El error esta dando en produccion con la aplicacion instalada en RDS un tipo de escritorio remoto para el control que los usuarios solo entren a esa aplicacion.

Comment: Ese error es muy genérico. Revisa el visor de eventos buscando ese error, o cualquier error relacionado con .Net Runtime a ver si obtienes algo mas de información.

Comment: Si ejecutas la app local en una pc, esta ejecuta sin errores? puede suceder que la ejecucion remota cause el problema. No se como implementan esto de RDS que mencionas, imagino debe ser que accedn al servidor usando Remote Desktop

Comment: Efectivamente de manera local no da problemas. Si puede ser la ejecucion remota tampoco tengo idea de porque cause problemas.